# Can a Cassandra cluster serve as a replacement for an in-memory Redis key-value store?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, key-value-store, nosql

My application crawls user's mailbox and saves it to an RDBMS database. I started using Redis as a cache (simple key-value store) for RDBMS database. But gradually I started storing crawler states and other data in Redis that needs to be persistent. Loosing this data means a few hours of downtime. I must ensure airtight consistency for this data. The data should not be lost in node failures or split brain scenarios. Strong consistency is a must. Sharding is done by my application. One Redis process runs on each of ten EC2 m4.large instances. On each of these instances. I am doing up to 20K IOPS to Redis. I am doing more writes than reads, though I have not determined the actual percentage of both. All my data is completely in memory, not backed by disk.

My only problem is each of these instances are SPOF. I cannot use Redis cluster as it does not guarantee consistency. I have evaluated a few more tools like Aerospike, none gives 'No data loss guarantee'.

Cassandra looks promising as I can tune the consistency level I want. I plan to use Cassandra with a replication factor 2, and a write must be written to both the replicas before considered committed. This gives 'No data loss guarantee.

By launching enough cassandra nodes (ssd backed) can I replace my Redis key-value store and still get similar read/write IOPS and
latency? Will opensource cassandra suffice my use case? If not, will the Datastax enterprise In-Memory version solve it?

EDIT 1:
A bit of clarification:
I think I need to use Write consistency level 'ALL' and Read consistency level 'One'. I understand that with this consistency level my cluster will not tolerate any failure. That is OK for me. A few minutes of downtime occasionally is not a problem, as long as my data is consistent. In my present setup, one Redis instance failure causes a few hours of downtime.

Comment: If "strong consistency is a must", then you will have to use SERIAL consistency, which comes with additional performance penalties.

Comment: I plan to use Write consistency level 'ALL' and Read consistency level 'One'.

Comment: That gives you *eventual* consistency for single rows. It does not give you isolation, nor does it allow you to make consistent changes across multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

> I must ensure airtight consistency for this data.

Cassandra deals with failure better when there are more nodes. Assuming your case allows for having more nodes, this is my suggestion.

So, if you have 5 nodes, use CL of QUORUM for both READ and WRITE. What it means is that you always write to at least 3 nodes and read from 3 nodes.(for 5 nodes , QUORUM is 3).

- This ensures a very high level consistency
- Also ensures limited downtime. Even if a node is down your writes and reads won't break.

If you use CL ALL, then even if one node is down or overloaded, you will have to take a full downtime.

I hope it helps!